# Problema com expressão regular no .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url-rewrite

Tenho a seguinte URL:

```
 http://< site >/restrito/usuarios/pagina/
```

Esta página é responsável por exibir uma tabela contendo os usuários cadastrados no sistema, pode receber como variável números para indicar a página da tabela, uma vez que eu mostro apenas valores de 20 em 20.

A expressão regular que resolveu o meu problema foi a seguinte:

```
RewriteRule ^restrito/usuarios/pagina/([^/.]+) restrito/usuarios.php?pagina=$1 [L]
```

O Problema é que quando eu utilizo `$` para indicar que a `ER` acaba ali  eu recebo o Error 404, e isso acontece com todas as outras Rules do meu `.htaccess`.

Alguém teria a solução para esse problema?

Comment: Utiliza `$` aonde? Na URL ou na regex?

Comment: na regex mesmo, a url deve ficar dessa maneira "http://< site >/restrito/usuarios/pagina/10" se a página for 10, por exemplo, na verdade só me chama atenção pois pelo pouco que eu sei de Expressão regulares, para finalizar a ER utiliza-se o $ e sempre quando eu faço uso do mesmo, recebo erro 404

Comment: Ainda não dá pra entender, você quer dizer que o problema ocorre quando faz isto `RewriteRule ^restrito/usuarios/pagina/([^/.]+)$`?

Comment: Exatamente isso @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Vou testar aqui e assim que conseguir edito a resposta ;)

Comment: Tranquilo, se você quiser eu posso copiar todo o arquivo .htaccess aqui, bem como explicar como está o diretório do site

Comment: Copia ele inteiro aqui por favor, deve ser conflito com outra regra

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^restrito/ver/usuario/([^/.]+) restrito/ver/usuario.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^restrito/usuarios/pagina/([^/.]+) restrito/usuarios.php?pagina=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^restrito/edit/usuario/([^/.]+) restrito/edit/usuario.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

</IfModule>               - O primeiro Rule é pra eu poder ignorar o .php dos arquivos

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver tentando passar uma *querystring* na URL reescrita como por exemplo:

```
http://< site >/restrito/usuarios/pagina/exemplo?foo=$
```

Então talvez tenha que adicionar a flag `QSA`

```
RewriteRule ^restrito/usuarios/pagina/([^/.]+) restrito/usuarios.php?pagina=$1 [L,QSA]
```